# Compare rest string angular

Tags: angular, string, spring-mvc, string-comparison, spring-restcontroller

I have to compare a string obtained from a rest function, but the comparison always returns false why? Thank you all!

Code method RestController

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/checkAnagraficaByMatricola", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public String checkAnagraficaByMatricola(@RequestParam(value = "matricola", required = true) int matricola) {
        
        System.out.println("check anagrafica");
        
        if(ans.visualizzaAnagraficaByMatricola(matricola) != null) 
            
            return "true";
        
        else
            
            return "false";
        
    }
```

Code angular

```
checkAnagrafica(matricola) {
    
    return this.hC.get<String>("http://localhost:8080/AnagraficaCurriculum-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/anagrafica/checkAnagraficaByMatricola?matricola="+matricola)
    
  }
```

```
check() {
    this.servizio.checkAnagrafica(this.anagrafica.matricola).subscribe(
      response=>{
        this.s = response;
         if(this.s === 'false')
           this.insert();
         else
           console.log("true");
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Did you try logging the response or setting a breakpoi t yo check what the response is?

Answer (score 0):

Basically Angular Http Client returns JSON by default.

Change your http call to the following with response type text:

```
checkAnagrafica(matricola) {
    
    return this.hC.get("http://localhost:8080/AnagraficaCurriculum-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/anagrafica/checkAnagraficaByMatricola?matricola="+matricola, {  responseType: 'text' });
    
  }
```